# Break statement completes abruptly or normally?

Tags: java

[**JLS 14.15:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)

> A break statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the
>   innermost enclosing switch, while, do, or for statement of the
>   immediately enclosing method or initializer;

I have misunderstanding about that rule. For example if we write the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) // Immediately enclosing method
{
    while(true){                       // Innermost enclosing 'while' for the break at LINE 2?
        break;                         // **LINE 2**
    }
}
```

JLS said when we was at `LINE 2` we attempted to transfer control to innermost enclosing `while`. What for? At `LINE 2` control is already at that while's `block-statement`.

Comment: The first statement of the JLS says "A break statement transfers control *out* of an enclosing statement."

Comment: @NathanMerrill Yes, it says. What JLS's trying to say by the rule I cited?

Comment: @St.Antario what it means is that if you have 2 nested loops and a break is inside the innermost loop, control is transferred to the outer loop. If you have 5 nested loops and a break is inside the inner most loop (the 5th one), then control is transferred to the 4th one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inspect the entire paragraph you're quoting (the sentence in **bold** was highlighted by me for clarity's sake):

> A `break` statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the innermost enclosing switch, while, do, or for statement of the immediately enclosing method or initializer; **this statement, which is called the break target, then immediately completes normally.**

In your example, control is transferred to the `while` statement in order to terminate, and move the execution on.

Answer (score 1):

it means if you have nested while loop, then it will break from innermost while. So for e.g.

```
//this is just a sample nonsensical code
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
      if (i > 100) {
        break;
      }
       while (true) {
         if (i < 20) {
           System.out.println("Inner while " + i);
           i++;
         } else {
           break;
         }
       }
       System.out.println("Outer while " + i);
       i ++;
    }
```

Observe the output. So when i is less then 20 it prints i's value from inner loop but soon when it goes to 20 it breaks from inner loop and returns to outer loop and start executing sysout from outer loop (although it goes in inner while but condition doesn't gets satisfied) and see that when i reaches  greater than 100 it break even from outer loop. Hope this helps.